# Does Tekton Triggers support HTTP GET requests?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, pipeline, webhooks, tekton

Does anyone know if Tekton event listeners and triggers work with HTTP GET requests?

Going off of this guide: https://tekton.dev/docs/getting-started/triggers/

I tried to create a binding that doesn't take any params, similar this:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerBinding
metadata:
  name: http-get-translater
spec:
  params:
  - name: placeholder
    value: nothing
```

But it always requires a `spec` with `params`.

The closest I got was a POST with an empty JSON, `{}`.  I could not even get things working with no JSON in the data payload.

Are GET requests not possible?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.